# combinations of sets and objects

Tags: combinations

How do I calculate how many combinations I can create with a set amount of categories and within each category, there are different amounts of objects. For example, if I have 5 categories (1,2,3,4,5) and within each category, there are different amounts of objects (cat1: 4, cat2: 5, cat3: 6, cat4: 7, cat5: 8), how many combinations can I make without changing the order? Like a combination lock with 5 digits, but each tumbler has different amounts of variables.

Sorry for my bad math language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Comment: The rule of product in the context of combinatorics loosely paraphrases as "If you wish to count the total number of outcomes to a scenario and each outcome can be *uniquely* described via a sequence of steps with choices such that the number of options for each step does not depend on previously made choices (*though the options themselves may change so long as the number of options does not*) (*uniquely meaning each outcome is described exactly once, no more and no less*), then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of choices available at each step"

Comment: Here, $4\times 5\times 6\times 7\times 8$ total outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at all the categories and how many choices you have, then multiply them. To use your example:

Category 1 has 4 objects, so you have 4 choices. Category 2 has 5 objects, so you have 5 choices. This means that you have $4\cdot5=20$ choices in categories 1 and 2.

If you do this for all categories you would have $4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8=6720$ choices overall.

Comment: thank you very much!